# Exact Diagonalization of a tight-binding Hamiltonian with periodically alternating potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, eigenvalue, tight-binding

My question is, can we diagonalize a general Hamiltonian ,
$$H=-t\sum_i^N (c_i^{\dagger}c_{i+1}+h.c.)+\sum_i \mu_i c_i^{\dagger}c_i$$ where,
$$\mu_i=\begin{cases}
\mu_0, &\text{if mod}(i,p)=0 \\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Obviously, $p$ is the periodicity of the lattice and $c$ is Fermionic annihilation operator. I know $p=2,3,4$  will have an analytic solution but from [Abel-Ruffini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) $p=5$ onwards may or may not have an analytic solution. Now I am sure because of periodicity there should be a certain degree of symmetry present in solutions, from Bloch's theorem, but I just cannot find a method to analytically solve the problem to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Numerically, I have found the solution, but any suggestions to solve it analytically?

Comment: "obviously" there is a solution for every p integer, but for p>=0 this solution may not be algebraic/analytical.

Comment: May I ask a question: Which physical system you have in mind?

Comment: @sintetico correct, I will edit my wording.

Comment: @sintetico I don't really have any particular system in mind, this was a general curiosity. maybe you can take a 1D lattice of electrons and introduce an external potential at certain lattice sites via laser? This is a long shot though.

Comment: In the Harper-Hofstadter model, one considers $\mu=\cos{(2\pi (p/q) n)}$

Comment: Yes I think p/q is irrational there?There is a perturbative series solution to this one I think, at its critical point, where it's eigenfunctions have a fractal structure, as a continued fraction. Similar is te case for other discrete quasiperiodic potentials with multifractal wavefunctions, like fIbonacci potentials. However, I havent found references for periodic potentials, though those should have been done before the quasiperiodic ones.

Comment: An exact solution may not exist. You can certainly work out the nearly free electron limit, though. Also, the large $p$ limit with $\mu = \gamma/p$ ($\gamma$ finite) should correspond to the Krönig-Penny model with a delta potential, which has a well known description. Btw, hopping to the right is missing in your Hamiltonian.

Comment: @RoopayanGhosh p/q is rational, p and q are integer coprimes. I think I have an idea on how to calculate eigenfunctions and eigenvalues, with exact solution (no approximation) but not analytical. If you want, send me a private message

Comment: @Vivek Thanks for pointing it out. yes maybe it doesnt have an analytical solution, but I just want to ask around..

Comment: @sintetico I am not entirely sure how to send a message, new user, could you send me one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be treated as a tight-binding model with period $p$ and $p$ states in every site. One could do it by first introducing operators:
$$a_{l, \nu} = c_{pl +\nu}, \nu=0,...,p-1,$$
and then looking for plane wave solutions $\sim e^{ikl}$.

Comment: What do you mean by p states in every site, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your model as a single level for every $i$. In a more general model you have something like: $H = \sum_{i,\alpha,\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}c_{i,\alpha}^\dagger c_{i,\beta} - \sum_{i,\alpha,\beta}t_{\alpha\beta}c_{i,\alpha}^\dagger c_{i+1,\beta}$, which by Fourier transform is reduced to matrix diagonalization in $\alpha,\beta$ space. This is a standard tight-binding problem. So considering every $p$ sites in your as a cell in the Hamiltonian above, reduces your problem to this one.

Comment: Okay got it thanks, but that still does not supercede Abel's theorem right, I was actually thinking along the same lines because I expected p=5 would provide a 5th order characteristic equation, which probably does not have an analytical solution? At least matematica can't do it within a short period of time..

Comment: You will have to diagonalize $p\times p$ matrix, whose characteristic equation is a polynomial  of order $p$. So, generally speaking *mathematically* it may be not solvable. But you are dealing with a particularly simple problem, so the solution might exist for arbitrary $p$. From the physicists point of view the problem is exactly solvable, since one can find the roots if polynomial numerically... if one needs to get down to numbers.

Comment: Btw, you need h.c. only for the hopping term - the Hamiltonian looks ambiguous as it is written now

Comment: corrected. Yes I agree. I have actually done it numerically and got all the results, but, if I could do it analytically for any p maybe it would have given me new insight to some features of the problem. But let's see, I will see if I can find any tricks to do it.